# Setting Stereo Rendering Mode in Unity/Oculus

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I am trying to set the Stereo Rendering Mode to Single Pass for Oculus through Script. The value never gets changed, i.e., it stays the same as "Multi-Pass". Is there a way to set up Stereo Rendering Mode through script during runtime?
Thing is if I set it manually to Single-Pass and run the application in Editor, it works fine but then when I stop the run, the settings automatically changes to Multi-Pass.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR;

public class SteoreoRendering : MonoBehaviour
{
    XRSettings.StereoRenderingMode stereoRenderingMode;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        stereoRenderingMode = XRSettings.StereoRenderingMode.SinglePass;
        Debug.Log(stereoRenderingMode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code currently isn't setting anything, `XRSettings.StereoRenderingMode stereoRenderingMode;` is **not** a reference to the current settings.

All you are doing is creating a **new** variable `stereoRenderingMode` of **type** [`XRSettings.StereoRenderingMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRSettings.StereoRenderingMode.html) (which is an `enum`) and updating that variable its value to `XRSettings.StereoRenderingMode.SinglePass`, but after that you don't do anything with this value. it just gets cleaned up at the end of your function.

this is practically the same as doing the following, but instead with the enum `StereoRenderingMode`

```cs
string foo = "Hello";

void Start()
{
   foo = "world";
}
```

I don't think you are able to set the `Render mode` at run time (most likely because it needs to be known before building your application). if it would have been possible it would've (most likely) been done by setting the [`XRSettings.stereoRenderMode`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.XRSettings-stereoRenderingMode.html), but that is a *read only* property, meaning Unity doesn't intend for you to change it at runtime (at least not through that route.). and there is no function like `SetStereoRenderMode` either to set it through.

As far as I am aware the only place you can change it is under `Project settings > XR Plugin-in management > <Your XR device> > Render Mode` (if you are using the new XR plugin mangement system) [image]

or else under `Project Settings > Player > XR Settings > Stereo Rendering Mode` if you are using the old (deprecated) XR management system. [image]

Editing this setting should not be reset after each build/run though, make sure you save your project after changing it to `SinglePass` to ensure a reload won't reset it. If it still happens you might want to look as Unity's issue tracker if this is a known bug, and if not report it as a bug as it does sound like unintended behavior. (It doesn't reset back to MultiPass when I try it locally)

Comment: Hi thank you for the explanation. I also figured that I was not setting it. But in the new XR Plugin Management, there is no Single Pass option for Oculus. There is only SinglePass instanced. Is there a workaround for this? I do not want to use Deprecated XR Settings.